# How to use zf-apigility-admin-ui instead of zf-apigility-admin to enable/show Doctrine menu

Tags: php, doctrine, laminas-api-tools

i want to use the Doctrine menu in apigility but it is not yet available using the zf-apigility-admin as provided in the skeleton.

i tried asking in the github page https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin-ui/issues/5, and got this:

> This is because Doctrine UI is not ready yet. If you want use Doctrine with UI you should use https://github.com/fwahlqvist/zf-apigility-admin-ui

i installed the zf-apigility-admin-ui and made some changes to my configuration:

composer.json

```
"require": {
"php": ">=5.3.23",
"zendframework/zendframework": ">=2.3.2,<3.0.0",
"zfcampus/zf-apigility": "~1.0",
"zfcampus/zf-apigility-documentation": "~1.0",
"zfcampus/zf-development-mode": "~2.0",
"zfcampus/zf-apigility-doctrine": "dev-master",
"zfcampus/zf-hal": "dev-master#b911038fd47f4efa27aeb1a5a53ee272a0f26f56",
"hounddog/doctrine-data-fixture-module": "0.0.*"},
"require-dev": {
"zendframework/zftool": "dev-master",
"zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "dev-master",
"zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin": "~1.0",
"zfcampus/zf-apigility-welcome": "~1.0",
"zfcampus/zf-deploy": "~1.0",
"fzaninotto/faker": "dev-master",
"zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin-ui": "~1.0"}
```

development.config.php

```
'modules' => array(
'ZFTool',
'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Ui',
'ZF\Apigility\Welcome',
'ZF\Apigility\Doctrine\Admin',),
```

but i get 404 error when accessing `http://localhost:8888/apigility/ui#/`

> "The requested URL could not be matched by routing."

how can i use the apigility-admin-ui view, any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a way to enable Doctrine menu?

Comment: @AlexeyKosov yes, it can be enabled but it's not official. a user from github have forked it [here](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin-ui/issues/5). i encountered some bugs using it too